# Automatic restart of c++ process attached to a wamp server

Tags: c++, windows, apache, wamp, restart

I've been working on a computing server and I need to make sure it restart properly in case of crash. The computer restarts properly, so I'm trying to start my process.

Our server is a C++ executable attached to Apache on a wamp server, the whole thing on a Windows computer. So I need to find a way to :

1. Start Wamp when Windows restarts
2. Start my process when Wamp is ready

I found out how to start Wamp when Windows reboots but I'm stuck on how to get my process to start *when Wamp is ready*. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to create windows services out of regular processes. It's painless and you can set another service as a dependency, ensuring your process won't start before it.

[image]